# how does Android achieve restricting API's?

Tags: java, android, security, sdk, platform

I know there are API restrictions in Android platform and there is a @hide notation inside a comment block above each restricted API. If a blocked API is accessed, the system will throw an error. I wonder how Android acheives this behavior even if the API is a public member.